# MVC5 application doesn't respect configSource in conn string, on PROD only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

New MVC5 application. I'm using configSource to handle my connection strings like so:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConfigSections\db.config"></connectionStrings>
```

with a db.config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=OurServer;Initial Catalog=OurDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and this works fine on our DEV server, but fails on PROD with this:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server...
```

... the SQL error is, I believe, ASP.NET Identity trying to make a new local db and failing.

I would assume I did something dumb like pointing to the wrong name, but a) I have checked this as best I can, and dev and prod are set up the same way, and b) [MSDN_ice at the bottom of this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1967488/5627965.aspx?Scaffolding%20Error%20Unable%20to%20retrieve%20metadata%20Unable%20to%20open%20configSource) is describing something very similar.

Does anyone know what's happening here? It's not simply the prod server, either, because we have an MVC3 application that runs on the same website that uses configSource just fine. Looks like a combination of MVC5 + ???.

(I will, if needed, switch to the Web.Config.Debug/Release approach, but I'd rather not if this can be fixed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed something dumb. I had the wrong connection name in db.config. An older version of my app was using a conn string named ApplicationServices. The current version uses one named DefaultConnection. Somehow I had updated on DEV but not PROD (sigh).